# Capturing Script logs from a test case in SoapUI using groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

can someone help me with a script to capture script logs from a test case in soap UI using groovy scripting.

Comment: You will have to list out what you have tried; what's working, what isn't to expect an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@canpan the below code worked for me,thanks for your continued help

'

```
def logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor.getLogArea("script log")
def LogFile = new File ("I:/SOAP UI/AutomationFramework/script.txt")
LogFile.write("Generating Script Logs...\r\n")
if (logArea != null)
{
    def model = logArea.model
    if (model.size > 0)
    {
        for (c in 0..(model.size-1))
        {
            LogFile.append(model.getElementAt(c).toString() + "\r\n")
        }
    }
}
```

'

Answer (score 0):

Taken from here: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-NG/Export-http-log-to-a-file-with-groovy-script/td-p/198

Quick note that the script log only logs what log.info logs. Also logs are only put in the script log when you run the whole test case, not when you run the groovy script manually.

```
def logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor
if( logArea != null )
{
   def ix = logArea.indexOfTab( "Script log" );
   if( ix >= 0 )
   {
      def logPanel = logArea.getComponentAt( ix )
      def model = logPanel.logList.model
      if( model.size > 0 )
      {
         def out = new java.io.PrintWriter( "C:/pathtofile/myfile.log" )

         for( c in 0..(model.size-1) )
            out.println( model.getElementAt( c ))

         out.close()
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Canpan, I tried the above code but getting error stating indexOfTab() is of type string, not sure why I am getting this error as "script log" is a string which I am passing within indexOfTab()

Comment: Can you paste in the exact code you typed and also what version of soapui/ready api are you using? I've tested this code again and it works fine. There is a chance you have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Hi Canpan, please find the code below. def logArea = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.logMonitor
if( logArea != null )
{
   def ix = logArea.indexOfTab( "Script log" );
   if( ix >= 0 )
   {
      def logPanel = logArea.getComponentAt( ix )
      def model = logPanel.logList.model
      if( model.size > 0 )
      {
         def out = new java.io.PrintWriter( "C:/pathtofile/myfile.log" )

         for( c in 0..(model.size-1) )
            out.println( model.getElementAt( c ))

         out.close()
      }
   }
}

Comment: Please note i am using SoapUI 5.2.1

Comment: There is a good chance that is the case. If you are using the free version it may not have the logging needed for this.
Either way you should upgrade to 5.3 as it's the newest free version they have I believe.

If it does have the logging. You will see a logs button in the bottom left of the screen, if you click that you will be able to see the logs it is logging. If you don't see that, then you can't do it in the free version. The logs may only be in Ready API. http://i.imgur.com/59I9Kjn.png

Comment: I am able to see script logs tab enabled in my version of SOAPUI

Comment: Hm, because it's pretty much looking for the name of that tab. The script above isn't really complicated. Can you post a screenshot of the script/error you are getting? Just hoping to see something odd that looks off.